# How can I change codec parsing system in MjSip?

Tags: codec, audioformat, mjsip

I am working on a softphone project and using MjSip stack to create develop it. The core MjSip is only suporrted with PCMA/PCMU codecs. But I want to add some more codecs with it like G729, GSM, iLBC etc.

In MjSip the class **AudioSender.java** is a pure-java audio stream sender. It uses javax.sound package.
In that class **javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat** is used for formatting the audio stream with PCM signed, unsigned or float type.
It has done in MjSip like following.

```
AudioFormat.Encoding codec;
        if (pcmu) {
            codec = AudioFormat.Encoding.ULAW;
        } else if (linear_signed) {
            codec = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        } else if (pcma) {
            codec = AudioFormat.Encoding.ALAW;
        } else {
            codec = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED; // default
        }

if (sound)
         {  AudioFormat format=new AudioFormat(codec,sample_rate,8*sample_size,1,sample_size,sample_rate,big_endian);
            System.out.println("System audio format: "+format);
            audio_input=new AudioInput(format);
            sender=new RtpStreamSender(audio_input.getInputStream(),false,payload_type,frame_rate,frame_size,daddr,dport);
         }
```

But I have created my own package **org.mine.codec** including this classes

```
Codec.java (This is an Interface)
CodecAttribute.java
CodecUtils.java
CodecFactory.java
CodecG729.java
CodecPCMA.java
CodecPCMU.java
```

So I want to use this instead of that **AudioFormat.Encoding**. How should I construct my **AudioSender.java** class and what changed are needed in **RtpStreamSender.java class**?
Is it possible to ignore that **AudioFormat** class? If I have to use that what would be the constructor of **RtpStreamSender.java**?